# Image not getting uploded in path folder

Tags: php

my php code is not showing any error while uploding image in path folder which i have given in my root folder... Im using function to get the data from my images.php file. below are given code of my pages.

images.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
    if(empty($_FILES['profile'] ['name']) === true) {
        echo 'Please Choose a File';
    } else {
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_name = $_FILES['profile'] ['name'];
        $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['profile'] ['temp_name'];

        if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
            change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect File Type. Allowed: ';
            echo implode(', ', $allowed);
        }
    }
}
if (empty($user_data['zip_code']) === false) {
    echo '<img src="', $user_data['zip_code'], '" alt="',$user_data['first_name'], 'Profile Images">';
}
```

main function Codes...

```
function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
    $file_path = 'images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
}
```

Please help me our here as this code is not moving image file from temp location to path location.

Comment: Did you check the folder permission if its having write permission ?

Comment: i have placed an htaccess file to privent to give access to use of that folder... htaccess codes - Options -Indexes

Comment: Use `if(is_writable('images/profile')): $file_path... endif;`

Comment: Get rid of all the " === true". It is unneeded and clutters your code.

Comment: is the path writable? and try './images/profile/'